# zgrep multiple gz files in directory

Tags: bash, grep

I have problem executing `zgrep` command for looking for `word` in the directory where I have almost 1000 `*.gz` files.

I am trying with:

```
find /var/www/page/logs/ -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep '/index.php' {} \;
```

result is:

```
GET : '/index.php'
GET : '/index.php'
GET : '/index.php'
```

And it works.I get list of occurance of `index.php` with no file name where it was found. It is kind of useless for me unless i knew in which files (filename) it appears.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could supply the `-H` option to list the filename:

```
find /var/www/page/logs/ -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep -H '/index.php' {} \;
```

If you wanted only the list of matching files, use `-l`:

```
find /var/www/page/logs/ -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep -l '/index.php' {} \;
```

Comment: Nice! I'll concede your solution is more elegant than mine - though you should have thought of mine with your moniker!!! :-)

Comment: It works thank you ! ps. cant accept anwser for another 3 mins

Answer (score 4):

Make grep search in two files, then it will tell you which one it found it in:

```
find /var/www/page/logs/ -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep '/index.php' {} /dev/null \;
```

And it won't take long to search in /dev/null.

Here is an example without /dev/null:

```
zgrep chr your.gz
>chrMCHU - Calmodulin - Human, rabbit, bovine, rat, and chicken
>chrgi|5524211|gb|AAD44166.1| cytochrome b [Elephas maximus maximus]
```

and with /dev/null

```
zgrep chr your.gz /dev/null
your.gz:>chrMCHU - Calmodulin - Human, rabbit, bovine, rat, and chicken
your.gz:>chrgi|5524211|gb|AAD44166.1| cytochrome b [Elephas maximus maximus]
```

Comment: Although giving the expected result, I do not think it should be encouraged, especially with such an obvious correct way of doing it (which is just a `man grep` away, too). It might have its place, but to suggest it for a beginner seems counterproductive in the long run.

Comment: As a Perl enthusiast  (motto "There's More Than One Way To Do It") I would dispute that there is "an obvious correct way". Not all greps have the "-H" option, and the /dev/null trick is actually advocated by Grymoire here http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Grep.html

Comment: I've inverted my vote. It was not as common or old as I believed it to be actually, my bad! Although current BSDs, Busybox and of course GNU includes it, Solaris did not and it was only fairly recent (>2000) in some.

Comment: Thank you. Out of interest, how/where can you research variants like this? Is there a good reference website describing version differences for Unix tools?

Comment: Most projects have the man-pages available easy online, for the system I can't do a quick ssh to. In this case, checked OS X, FreeBSD and Solaris man-pages online (top results on google), as well as checked the source history in cvsweb for Open and NetBSD. There are cross referencing sites though (man-pages from different OS as well as soruce), but have yet to familiarize my self with a particular one.